# How does something become established in the world view of some particularly culture or group?

Tags: history-of-philosophy

How does something become established in the world view of some particularly culture or group?

Particularly, because one often meets terms such as "western thought", "eastern thought" and so. But are these factual in the sense that they would describe such large groups or is the distinction more like where the thoughts have originated from?

That is, western philosophers have written "western thought", but thoughts of western philosophers are not necessarily the thoughts of western people (even though I find that this is a common interpretation of these "world view" terms)?

Comment: See [Culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culture) and [Tradition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tradition).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes sure, but does that lead to there being "western thought" or does "western thought" mean the thinkers originated from western world or both? I find that people refer to "western thought" as if it was something that "everyone knows", which could be, but it could also be a limited view on the plethora of views that there are. In addition to writings often written by nobility of the past.

Comment: Western thought is originated from Western world; as long as the modern globalized world is looing barriers, worldviews become fuzzy.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA It's a good thing, because I've always found it a bit problematic that when one goes to school, one's world view tends to become hugely biased by a handful of academic thinkers. In the West we hear Aristotle, Rousseau, Hume and sorts. But these are just a handful of people from very large. In addition as humanists, novelists and so on they are not necessarily expressing reality things, but ideals that may be different from the PRACTICAL life of the times.

Comment: A common flaw of philosophers and writers is that they "live" in a too idealized world, "have never held a proper job" etc. So then it creates a flawed idea of times for example if time periods are defined as/by some kind of "ism" by some philosophers.

Comment: Young people learn values, and traditions and "ways to live and behave" from ap rents and school and "enighbours" well before studying Aristotle or Rousseau.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, but when one looks back, then is it perhaps sometimes that "the winners write the history". That is, if one studies back, then one gets information that's passed on by "winners" of some sort. In academic history at least.

Comment: Seems like a question better suited to [psychology.stackexchange.com](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/); there's little reason to think philosophers have any particularly novel means of memetic exchange.

Comment: What is this compulsion?  It's a good question. Like here, we have an anti-religious ministry. A what!?  The church of God with no God!?  Huh?https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wise_Blood  And this book:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christ_Recrucified  Two great writers, Kazantzakis and O'Conner, essentially write the same book.

Comment: There is a compulsion to keep coming back to the same question over and over again. This means the very thing we deny is still an important issue for us, as individuals and as societies.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think reading up on postmodernism might give you more insight to the question. Anyway, I think that "where the thoughts have originated from" is usually exactly the answer. An example would be [Continental Philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continental_philosophy), although the main common connection in this philosophy is that they're outside the analytic school, there isn't much more to that, and as the name suggests the next connecting element is being originated in Mainland Europe.